# How to get email claim in Angular - Spring Boot - Auth0

Tags: angular, spring-boot, auth0

I have a Spring boot app, with Angular frontend integrated with Auth0. The security is working ok. But I want to get user email on spring side,

I added below code in an endpoint

```
@GetMapping(value = "/private")
public Message privateEndpoint(@AuthenticationPrincipal Jwt jwt) {
    Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getClaims();
    for (Object key: claims.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("key: and value: "+ key.toString());// + "..."+  claims.get(key).asString());
    }
```

**SCENARIO 1 :**
Client is Postman.

scope = openid profile email

access token url = https://{{auth0_domain}}/oauth/token

Log:

```
key: and value: sub
key: and value: aud
key: and value: azp
key: and value: scope
key: and value: iss
key: and value: exp
key: and value: iat
```

**SCENARIO 2:**

Testing from angular gives null pointer (jwt) at line

System.out.println("headers:\n" + jwt.getHeaders());

It seems something is missing in angular request. Not sure what it is.

Some angular code:

```
  responseType: 'token id_token',
    audience: 'http://localhost:8080',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200/callback',
    scope: 'openid email view:some view:another'



  private setSession(authResult): void {
    // Set the time that the access token will expire at 
    const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
    localStorage.setItem('access_token', authResult.accessToken);
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', authResult.idToken);
    localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt);
  }
```

Question: How to log email address on spring side?
Why angular request is giving null pointer?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Followed the below article

https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-angular-spa

But I'm having issue in identifying my uri

```
  // Matching on HTTP method
  {
    uri: '/api/orders',
    httpMethod: 'post',
    tokenOptions: {
      audience: 'http://my-api/',
      scope: 'write:orders',
    },
  },
```

Flow: Button has [routerLink]="['/todo', fid,sid]

**app-routing** has

```
{
        path: 'todo/:sId/:tId', // child route path cid/:sid/:tid
        component: ThatComponent, // child route component that the router renders
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      },
```

**app.module**

```
 httpInterceptor: {
    allowedList: [                 
                   {
                     uri: '/*',
                     tokenOptions: {
                       audience: 'http://localhost:8080',
                       scope: 'view:account',
                     },
                   },

    ],
```

I use proxy config to map angular endpoints (4200) to spring (8080) for any /server i.e. return this.http.get('/server/api/v1/...')

So unable to identify the right uri ( instead of  uri: '/*',)

Any idea?

Answer (score -1):

ok found the issue.
http.get  was  having legacy model (removed it)

```
{headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)}
```

uri now accespts   uri: '/server/api/..*' **matching** url in the call this.http.get(**url**)